# Slim framework works on http but not https

Tags: php, wordpress, https, slim

I have a wordpress site running which is set to use HTTPS, Within the wordpress site I have a widget in a theme that is using the Slim framework. When running on HTTP it does work well but with HTTPS I do get 404 error. The ajax calls are initiated from the browser and request sources that are on the same domain.

Browser log says: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxxxxxxx.xxx' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Within the app only relative path is used. Within the html source I see some HTTP requests for images etc. but it doesn't complain about them

Comment: Many browsers deliberately block JavaScript (and thus AJAX) requests via HTTP, if the the website is delivered via HTTPS. You could fix this by making sure that JavaScript requests use HTTPS, too.

Comment: I have now added https:// in the javascript file, but still got the following error: Mixed Content: The page at 'xxxxxxx/'; was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'xxxxxxxx/wp-content/themes/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lastupdate';‌​. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. In my javascript I have: function getStarted() { request = $.ajax({ type: GET, url: HTTPS://xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx, data: {}, dataType: json })

Comment: After changing everything back to non https I get a 404 (not found) however on the developmachine it is working and also on the test server which is also out in the internet. Bsically it doesn't find the routes that are described in the index.php like the student starter app for Slim. Can it be related to the fact that the WP-JSON plugin has been installed? I do see some variations in the header between the test and the production environment ( link http://xxxxxxxxx/wp-json/>:rel=HTTPS://api.w.org/ )

Answer (score 0):

For your ajax urls make sure that they start with https://  or just //